# Does Swagger documentation create controller or route when executing (C# Rest Api)?

Tags: c#, swagger

I am trying to set rights (according to my own database repository) to my C# Rest Api Swagger documentation.
In other words, I would like to decide who can display the Swagger documentation for my Rest Api.
I would like to know how does Swagger works.
Does it create controllers, routes when executing which I can catch by code to check the rights before displaying ?
What are the objects I can interact with ?
I would like to read the current routes to check in my database who can display documentation for this route.
Thank you very much in advance.
Eric.

Comment: Swagger is much more about automatic OpenAPI service description generation, developing and testing rather then running some web methods in production accordingly to caller permissions. You can show swagger in the developer|testing environment only. This will keep your production data safe

Comment: By "Swagger" do you mean Swashbuckle?